# Display Hour and Minutes

Tags: crystal-reports

I got two fields in my table which is `Hour` and `Minutes`. How do I display it to my report that will look like this format `HH:MM`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below formula.

ToText(datetime field, "hh:mm")

Comment: can you show me the exact whole thing to do? i got my two fields in my one table and i need to display it like this format hh:mm?

Comment: Please refer this .. http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=149...if you need any more help. Please let me know.

Comment: @Ralph two fields ?? Separate for hour's and min?

Comment: yes and i want to merge them in crystal report with a format like this hh:mm. i have two time fields one is hour and two is minutes

Comment: If you have two separate fields for both then just drag drop them to report and use a text for :.  It will be so simple.

Comment: It will help you step by step.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18332/Crystal-Report-Basics-and-Integration-with-DataSet

Comment: thank you @Janty. I am so dumb why I havent think of that. I overthink this simple problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Right click The Field You Will Get The

->Format Editor

In Date and Time Column you can change the date Format .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Create a formula `@Display` and write as below

```
ToText(Hour)+" : "+ToText(Minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add text object to canvas
- drag and drop each field to a text object
- edit the text object and add a ":".
- while in edit mode, right click each field and change its formatting to remove decimal points.